# Quant Interview - Best time to buy and short stock with position constraint

Tags: algorithmic-trading

I was given a problem at a job interview, I'm trying to solve it afterwards

You are given a list of N trades for some stock, you need to determine how much volume for each trade an ideal strategy would execute, provided that you cannot buy or short more than K (=const) shares. The algorithm should work for O(N) and be constant in memory.

It is clear how to solve such a problem by dynamic programming (with memory O(K) and complexity O(N * K) = O(N)), but the running time on 1e5 trades is about a couple of hours, although it is necessary to work for a couple of seconds. Maybe there are some optimisations for such dynamics?

(fyi. $d[i][p] = max(d[i-1][p],\,\,\,\, d[i-1][p - \text{side_sign} * x] - \text{side_sign} \cdot x \cdot \text{trade['price']}$ $x \in [1, \text{ trade['amount']}])$, $\text{side_sign = (-1 if trade['side'] == 'short' else 1)}$)

Answer (score 0):

A promising approach to solving this task involves using Cartesian coordinates to represent two variables: position and USD balance. The first trade generates a segment within these coordinates, defined as $(\text{side_sign} * x,\; -\; \text{side_sign} * \text{trade['price']} * x),\; x \in [0,\;\text{trade['amount']}]$ where $x$ ranges from 0 to the trade's amount. When we introduce a subsequent trade, also represented similarly, we expand the set to include all potential outcomes for position and USD balance after partially executing the two considered trades.

As we continue to add more trades, we generate a larger set of potential outcomes. The key insight is this: rather than maintaining a record of all individual points that could arise from these multiple combinations, it's sufficient to focus on the convex hull of this set. Each new trade can then be used to update this convex hull. Finally, once all trades have been considered, it's easy to identify the point on the convex hull that intersects the balance-axis at the highest USD balance while zeroing out the position.

Comment: Hi Mark: Concentrating on your original question and not your answer, could you explain how the formula in the fyi part of your question is obtained. I couldn't even think about your question because I had no clue about the formula. Maybe that was the case for others also ? But it sounds like you definitely know what you're doing about it without any replies !!!!!! Thanks.

Comment: Hi there,
d[i][p] -- this is maximal profit using first i trades and having p stocks.

Comment: let the current trade be a sell-trade of N stocks.

so the value of d[i][p] is maximum of d[i-1][p] (i.e. not using i-th trade at all) and all possible values d[i-1][p + x] + price[i] * x, where x from 1 to N (here we use  d[i-1][p + x] because we updating element with position p and we sell x stocks, so need to use previous element with position p + x)
(sorry for the double comment, I'm just going over the edition limit)

Comment: Thanks Mark. So, aside from the maximum restriction, you are given a list at on day $D$ of the stocks ( and their respective amounts ) you should have bought and shorted on day $D-1$.

Comment: also, why is it price[i] * x. Does that mean that if  you shorted it yesterday then you would have received that price[i] for that stock ? The prices are known I assume since it's day D and the data is from day (D - 1) ?

Comment: as for price[i] * x:
You update d[i][p] -- using i trades optimal pnl with position p, so you have to use i-th trade price: price[i]. x here is for possible execution amount.

My case is for short trade (so i-th trade is short trade), so if you choose to execute some amount of that trade you will get corresponding amout of quote asset i.e. for x stocks you will get price[i] * x of quote asset (wlog dollars)

Comment: You are given a list of trades and you have to decide which trades and how much you want to participate in to maximise your pnl